# With Beamer the article and presentation options create a spurious par

Tags: beamerarticle

Using the Beamer `article` and `presentation` options I coded the following:

```
Quadrant \presentation{\Romanbar{1}\xspace}\article{I\xspace} (lagging) 
and \presentation{\Romanbar{4}}\article{I\hspace{-1pt}V}  (leading)
```

And with either option this incorrectly produces:

```
Quadrant
I
(lagging) and 
IV
(leading)
```

because I need everything in one line.

I also tried coding the following commands, but this also fails:

```
\newcommand\Roma{\presentation{\Romanbar{1}\xspace}\article{I\xspace}}
\newcommand\Romb{\presentation{\Romanbar{2}}\article{I\hspace{-1pt}I}}
\newcommand\Romc{\presentation{\Romanbar{3}}\article{I\hspace{-1pt}I\hspace{-1pt}I}}
\newcommand\Romd{\presentation{\Romanbar{4}}\article{I\hspace{-1pt}V}}
```

Is there a workaround?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\setjobnamebeamerversion{main.beamer}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{romanbar}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand\Roma{\presentation{\Romanbar{1}\xspace}\article{I\xspace}}
\newcommand\Romb{\presentation{\Romanbar{2}}\article{I\hspace{-1pt}I}}
\newcommand\Romc{\presentation{\Romanbar{3}}\article{I\hspace{-1pt}I\hspace{-1pt}I}}
\newcommand\Romd{\presentation{\Romanbar{4}}\article{I\hspace{-1pt}V}}

\begin{document}
Quadrant \presentation{\Romanbar{1}\xspace}\article{I\xspace} (lagging) 
and \presentation{\Romanbar{4}}\article{I\hspace{-1pt}V}  (leading)

vs

Quadrant {I\xspace} (lagging) 
and {I\hspace{-1pt}V}  (leading)

\end{document}
```

On overleaf gives:

[image]

The Beamer MWE:

```
\documentclass[9pt, %handouts,
ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[landscape,a4paper,border shrink=5mm]\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}

\setjobnamebeamerversion{main.beamer}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{romanbar}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand\Roma{\presentation{\Romanbar{1}\xspace}\article{I\xspace}}
\newcommand\Romb{\presentation{\Romanbar{2}}\article{I\hspace{-1pt}I}}
\newcommand\Romc{\presentation{\Romanbar{3}}\article{I\hspace{-1pt}I\hspace{-1pt}I}}
\newcommand\Romd{\presentation{\Romanbar{4}}\article{I\hspace{-1pt}V}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    

Quadrant \presentation{\Romanbar{1}\xspace}\article{I\xspace} (lagging) 
and \presentation{\Romanbar{4}}\article{I\hspace{-1pt}V}  (leading)

vs

Quadrant \Romanbar{1} (lagging) 
and \Romanbar{4}  (leading)

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: please provide aan example that produces the output shown, where is \Romanbar defined?  Possibly unrelated `\xspace` appears mis-used here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Sorry tried `\xspace` to fix the issue.

Comment: I have defined `\newcommand{\rom}[1]{\Romanbar{#1}}` as a placeholder in the mean time.

Comment: `\mbox{Quadrant \presentation{\Romanbar{1}}\article{I} (lagging) and \presentation{\Romanbar{4}}\article{I\hspace{-1pt}V} (leading)}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have many more to do and would prefer a replacement using `\rom{1}` ... `\rom{4}`.  The solution suggested is too specific.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have decided to use `\newcommand\romd{ \mbox{\presentation{\Romanbar{4}}\article{I\!V}}\xspace}` from your suggestion.  Can you please either post that or `\newcommand\rom[#1]{` as a solution please so that I can accept it as answer?

Answer (score 1):

You only need `\only<`*mode*`>`

```latex
\iftrue% \iftrue or \iffalse
    \documentclass{beamer}
\else
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{beamerarticle,pgfkeys}
\fi

\usepackage{romanbar}

\pgfkeys{
    /skvery/rom/.cd,
    1/.initial={I},
    2/.initial={I\!I},
    3/.initial={I\!I\!I},
    4/.initial={I\!V},
    5/.initial={V},
    6/.initial={V\!I},
}
\def\skveryrom#1{\preORart{\Romanbar{#1}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/skvery/rom/#1}}}
\def\preORart#1#2{\only<presentation>{#1}\only<article>{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Two mode Roman numbers}
        Roman one \skveryrom{1}
        \pause
        Roman two \skveryrom{2}
        \pause
        Roman three \skveryrom{3}
        \pause
        Roman four \skveryrom{4}
        \pause
        Roman five \skveryrom{5}
        \pause
        Roman six \skveryrom{6}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

⬆️ in presentation mode

[image]

⬆️ in article mode

Comment: Can you define the macro so that I can use `\roma{1}` or `\roma{4}` in the text?